# CXF SpringComponentScanServer usage

Tags: java, spring-boot, cxf

I want to configure CXF to auto-scan for resources, providers, features, and the lot. In my search I came across the `SpringComponentScanServer`, which sounds like something I need. Unfortunately, documentation about this class is virtually non-existent.

When you have classes annotated with `@javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`, they get picked up by CXF as expected. When you have a feature annotated with `org.apache.cxf.annotations.Provider`, it will also get picked up by CXF.

But what if you have a third-party feature that does not have this annotation?
For example, the CXF `LoggingFeature`? You cannot, as far as I know, add an annotation to a class if you can't change it's source code.

I came up with the following, hideous, solution, but surely, there must be a better way to do this???

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringComponentScanServer.class)
public class CxfConfig {

    @Component
    @Provider(Provider.Type.Feature)
    static class MyLoggingFeature extends LoggingFeature {
    }
}
```

Here, I basically extend the existing LoggingFeature, only to add the `@Provider` annotation.

I found the following example [CXF JAXRS Spring Boot example](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/jaxrs_spring_boot), which does what I want with the Swagger2Feature. That works, but only starting from CXF 3.1.6, and only for the Swagger2Feature. Not for LoggingFeature.

So my question is: is there a less hideous way to add the LoggingFeature?